# Prove that 12 has no primitive root

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So I've got to prove that there exists no integer $a$ such that $a$ has order 4 mod 12. How can I do this?

EDIT: Can I just try every integer less 12 and co-prime to 12 i.e. 5,7,11
Why does it suffice to consider only integers less than 12?

Comment: Exhaustive search is easy enough. Or you could use the Chinese remainder theorem to determine the structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Does his question mean that there is no integer $a$ such that $a^{4} \equiv 1\pmod{12}$??

Comment: @Chandrasekhar No, that holds for all $a$ coprime to $12$. It means there is no integer $a$ such that $a^k \not\equiv 1 \pmod{12}$ for $k\in \{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks Dan. Sorry was not familiar with term *order* $\pmod{12}$

Comment: @DanielFischer Did you see my edit?

Comment: Not before, @user108605. Yes, that suffices. Because $a\equiv b \pmod{m} \implies a^k \equiv b^k \pmod{m}$ for all $k$, so you only need to check bases between $0$ and $12$; and if $a$ is not coprime to $12$, then of course $a^k$ isn't coprime to $12$ for any $k > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would suffice to check that there is no positive integer less than $12$ that has order $4$. You ask about why it suffices to check only numbers less than $12$. Mechanically, this is because if $a \equiv b \pmod {12}$, then $a^k \equiv b^k \pmod {12}$, so that being equivalent mod $12$ completely determines behaviour. Intuitively, this is because there are only $12$ numbers mod $12$ (and only $4$ numbers in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}^{12})^\times)$.

As an aside, we consider this from a slightly more sophisticated point of view. We are trying to determine the structure of the group $\left(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}^{12}\right)^\times$, which is sometimes denoted $U(12)$ or $U_{12}$, the group of units. This group consists of those elements relatively prime to $12$ under multiplication. There are $4$ elements, so asking whether any element has order $4$ is asking whether or not $U(12)$ is cyclic.

Determining the structures of the groups $U(n)$ is a fundamental question in the study of elementary number theory. It turns out that these groups are cyclic if and only if $n = 2, 4, p^k$ or $2p^k$ for odd primes $p$ and positive integers $k$. This is proved in most elementary number theory books and (likely) multiple times on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that checking $n$ has a primitive root or not is same as checking whether $U(n)$  is a cyclic group or not.

Now is $U(n)$ cyclic?